# MakeFile problem only have .Object files

Tags: make, c++

As the title say i have a problem compiling so i have my makefile who compile great my .cpp , then I have .o in the bin directory but after that its off I stay with my .o files and nothing change ,
It seems it doesnt take into account the few lines i wrote after and cant have my .exe
PLEASE HLEP ME

```
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#

#   MAKEFILE of the Radio Simulation Program

#

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 03/05/21  Creation

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------





# Define options and paths

CFLAGS = -Wall -O

SRCDIR = ./Src

INCDIR = ./Inc

BINDIR = ./Bin

TARGET = ./Bin



# Program name

EXE_PROG = $(BINDIR)/simradio.exe

all = $(EXE_PROG)



all: $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o  $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o  $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o 



# Source file compilations



$(BINDIR)/SimMain.o: $(SRCDIR)/SimMain.cpp

    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o -c $(SRCDIR)/SimMain.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

    



$(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o: $(SRCDIR)/classConfigCtx.cpp

    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o -c $(SRCDIR)/classConfigCtx.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o: $(SRCDIR)/ClassRadMgr.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o -c $(SRCDIR)/ClassRadMgr.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o: $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSlot.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o -c $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSlot.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o: $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSrv.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o -c $(SRCDIR)/GesCanSrv.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)



$(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o: $(SRCDIR)/SupSrv.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o -c $(SRCDIR)/SupSrv.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

    

$(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o: $(SRCDIR)/AppliMsg.cpp

    g++  -o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o -c $(SRCDIR)/AppliMsg.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)

    



$(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o: $(SRCDIR)/AgentSNMP.cpp

    g++ -o $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o -c $(SRCDIR)/AgentSNMP.cpp $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCDIR)
    

# default target
$(TARGET): $(OBJ_LIST)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ_LIST) $(CFLAGS)


# Object files list

OBJ_LIST =  $(BINDIR)/AgentSNMP.o $(BINDIR)/AppliMsg.o $(BINDIR)/classConfigCtx.o $(BINDIR)/ClassRadMgr.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSlot.o $(BINDIR)/GesCanSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SupSrv.o $(BINDIR)/SimMain.o

help:
    echo $(OBJ_LIST)



# Erase the former binary files

mrproper: clean

    rm -f $(EXE_PROG):$(OBJ_LIST)

    g++ -g -o $(EXE_PROG) $(OBJ_LIST)
```

Comment: You have a variable called `all`, and a target called `all`.  Building the `all` target will not build the file referenced by the variable. In fact, you appear to have no rule for building the actual executable.  There is also a comment saying "default target" further down, which is odd because the default target is the _first_ target in the file, i.e. `all`.  That later target is also referencing a `TARGET` variable, which seems to hold the value of a directory path, which does not make much sense to me. It looks as if this was put together from two separate Makefiles.

Comment: I'm also wondering about the `rm -f` command in the `mrproper` target. What do you mean by the `:` between the values of the two variables there?  That `mrproper` target also depends on some `clean` target that I can't actually find.  Was this lifted from a Linux kernel Makefile? Why does the `mrproper` target (which does cleaning up) call `g++` to compile the code (wasn't the object files just deleted?!)

Comment: hello @Kusalananda and thanks for your feedback , so yes in fact i'm new to makefile and doesnt understand that much , actually for TARGET I took this on internet and i removed it since it doesn't change anything , Since I have a main (SimMain) , I dont get how I can get my .exe with all the .object files

Comment: All the compiles to .o follow an identical pattern, with just the stem like `SupSrv` changing. Make is very good at using rules to implement these. You can also create lists of names to have them all be built with one line.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Thanks you for you comment however I actually dont know How I can transform this ***** .object files ^_^  Could make an example for one ?